# Not able to access a INSTANCE variable in python

Tags: python, oop, methods, instance-variables, python-class

```
class Atm:
    def __init__(self):
        self.pin = ""
        self.balance = 0
        
        
    def menu(self):
            ask = int(input("""

            Select from the menu
            1. Press 1 to set your pin
            2. Press 2 to deposit
            3. Press 3 to withdrawl
            4. Press 4 to check balance
            5. Press 5 to exit
        
            :  """))
            if ask == 1:
                self.create_pin()
            elif ask == 2:
                self.deposit()
            
    def create_pin(self):
        self.pin = input(" Set your pin : ")
        print(" Pin sucesfully set ")
    
    
    def deposit(self):
        print(self.pin)
        tmp = input(" Enter your pin : ")
        if tmp == self.pin:
            amount = float(input(" Enter your deposit amount  : "))
            self.balance = amount + self.balance
            print(" Amount Deposit sucessfully ")
        else:
            print(" Wrong Pin ")
            
                       
        
        

sbi = Atm()
sbi.menu()
```

Hello Everyone,

Here I am writing a very simple program for ATM machine. I already created a instance variable called self.pin and I assign a value inside it using " create_pin " method but when I am trying to use this variable inside method " deposit ", I am not able to access it and it always going inside else condition and getting output wrong pin.

step to reproduce -:

1. Run the program
2. select 1 to set pin and set the pin - 1234
3. Run the Program
4. select 2 to deposit and enter the pin - 1234
   output -: wrong pin

expectation -: It should match the temp variable with pre set pin and if pin is correct, it should allow user to deposit the amount.

Problematic Method -: deposit()

Comment: Nothing is saved when you run the program twice. If you run `sbi.menu()` twice it will work. You will need to store your pin in a file or similar if you want to keep it over multiple file runs.

Comment: I added this small part in my code after your suggestion and it worked -: {   sbi = Atm()        
while True:
    sbi.menu()  } can I create a empty list variable in constructor and append the value directly inside it from other methods??  Thank you sooo much